# matplotlib: change position of rectangle by slider

Tags: object, matplotlib, widget, slider, rectangles

I am trying to change the xy position of my drawn rectangle by changing the slider. I achieved this for an ellipse but for the rectangle it is not working. I have no idea why?!

[matplotlib widgets slider on object (Ellipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649131/matplotlib-widgets-slider-on-object-ellipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Rectangle` does not have `.center`

Try using

```
def update(val):
    Spiegel.set_xy((val,0))
```